# Autowired not working as expected

Tags: spring, autowired

I'm using Spring Roo and want to access a bean within of Controller class which has following configuration in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="com.reservation.jobs.Configuration" id="jobsConfiguration" autowire="byType">
 <property name="skipWeeks" value="4" />
</bean>
```

The configuration class itself is:

```
package com.reservation.jobs;

public class Configuration {
 private int skipWeeks;

 public void setSkipWeeks(int value) {
  System.out.println("SkipWeeks set auf: " + value);
  this.skipWeeks = value;
 }
 public int getSkipWeeks() {
  return this.skipWeeks;
 }
}
```

In my Controller I thought that a simple Autowired annotation should do the job

```
public class SomeController extends Controller {
 @Autowired
 private com.reservation.jobs.Configuration config;

}
```

During startup Spring prints the message within the setSkipWeeks method. Unfortunately whenever I call config.getSkipWeeks() within the controller it returns 0.

Have I to use the getBean method of the ApplicationContext instance or is there some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autowire="byType"` is redundant. It indicates that fields of the `Configuration` class should be autowired, and you have just one primitive. So remove that attribute.

Apart from that, `config.getSkipWeeks()` must return `4` unless:

- you are using a different instance (made by you with `new`)
- you have called the setter somewhere with a value of 0